# How to rename return Tuples Items?

Tags: c#, methods, tuples, console-application, c#-7.0

I am new to C# new feature Called as Tuples. I wrote some code on Tuple. when the Tuple is return by a Method (Tuple contains multiples values).

i-e

```
string firstNumber = separateNumbers.Item1;
string secondNumber = separateNumbers.Item2;
string thirdNumber = separateNumbers.Item3;
string fourthNumber = separateNumbers.Item4;
```

In the real word scenario it get complicated to identify which item contain which value ?

So I want to provide some specific name instead of item1,item2, etc...
How to do that ?

Thanks in Advance.

**Code:**

```
namespace CSharp_Tuples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string PhoneNumbers = "+92315 +92316 +92317 +92318";
            var separateNumbers = GetIndividualNumbers(PhoneNumbers);

            string firstNumber = separateNumbers.Item1;
            string secondNumber = separateNumbers.Item2;
            string thirdNumber = separateNumbers.Item3;
            string fourthNumber = separateNumbers.Item4;

            Console.WriteLine(firstNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(secondNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(thirdNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(fourthNumber);

        }
        static Tuple<string, string, string, string> GetIndividualNumbers(string allNumbers)
        {
            string[] numbers  = allNumbers.Split(' ');
            return Tuple.Create<string,string,string,string>(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tuples don't appear to be the correct type to use here. Why is 4 the magic number? What happens if there's 5 or 6 numbers? Even if you "know" somehow that today there's only ever 4 numbers, it would *still* make more sense to use a `List` or `string[]`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert):  This is a sample  code for my question....

Comment: Doesn't mean I can't argue for a better sample. :-) A tuple with (say) first name, last name and telephone number would make a little more sense. `Tuple` does not support naming its fields; `ValueTuple` does. [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [C# 7.0 tuples feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) uses [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple), not the old [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple).

With that feature, you can do something like this:

```
namespace CSharp_Tuples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string PhoneNumbers = "+92315 +92316 +92317 +92318";

            var numbers = UsingValueTuple(PhoneNumbers);

            Console.WriteLine("firstNumber : " + numbers.firstNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("secondNumber : " + numbers.secondNumer);
            Console.WriteLine("thirdNumber : " + numbers.thirdNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("fourthNumber : " + numbers.fourthNumber);
        }

        static (string firstNumber, string secondNumer, string thirdNumber, string fourthNumber) UsingValueTuple(string allNumbers)
        {
            string[] numbers = allNumbers.Split(' ');
            return (numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Further i studied this problem and i get the conclusion.

**Conclusion:**

With respect to Question:

> So I want to provide some specific name instead of item1,item2, etc...
>   How to do that ?

- Tuples can't allow us to rename the return values Instead We can make use of 
  **anonymous type**.

**Code:**

```
namespace CSharp_Tuples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string PhoneNumbers = "+92315 +92316 +92317 +92318";

            //var separateNumbers = GetIndividualNumbers(PhoneNumbers);

            //string firstNumber = separateNumbers.Item1;
            //string secondNumber = separateNumbers.Item2;
            //string thirdNumber = separateNumbers.Item3;
            //string fourthNumber = separateNumbers.Item4;

            //Console.WriteLine(firstNumber);
            //Console.WriteLine(secondNumber);
            //Console.WriteLine(thirdNumber);
            //Console.WriteLine(fourthNumber);


            var numbers = Cast(usingAnonymouseObject(PhoneNumbers), new {
                                                                        firstNumber = "",
                                                                        secondNumer = "",
                                                                        thirdNumber = "",
                                                                        fourthNumber = ""
                                                                        });
            Console.WriteLine("firstNumber : " + numbers.firstNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("secondNumber : " + numbers.secondNumer);
            Console.WriteLine("thirdNumber : " + numbers.thirdNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("fourthNumber : " + numbers.fourthNumber);


        }
        //static Tuple<string, string, string, string> GetIndividualNumbers(string allNumbers)
        //{
        //    string[] numbers  = allNumbers.Split(' ');
        //    return Tuple.Create<string,string,string,string>(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3]);
        //}

        static object usingAnonymouseObject(string allNumbers)
        {
            string[] numbers = allNumbers.Split(' ');
            return new { firstNumber = numbers[0], secondNumer = numbers[1], thirdNumber = numbers[2], fourthNumber = numbers[3] };
        }

        static T Cast<T>(object obj, T type)
        {
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }
}
```

---